# Facebook Product Catalogs Graph Api Explorer Showing Empty Result

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph-api-explorer

I wanted to test Facebook Page Product Catalogs API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/product_catalogs/) at Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/). The request submitted successfully without error, but just with empty result, which is not reflecting what my public Facebook UI is showing.

Prior to that I've enabled the `Shop` tab in my Facebook page and added a dummy product there. The product went through Facebook review successfully and it is visible to public now. I've also added a Facebook app to interact with the Facebook page. I am the admin of both the FB page + app and able to get `manage_pages` permission in Graph API Explorer without any problem.

However, when I request for product catalogs of the page, it shows empty result without any error (Refer attached print screen). I tried both user and page token also showing empty result without error. I tried to use the same token to extract the Facebook page's posts and able to get posts correctly, so it seems like my token is able to access the page correctly, just don't know why there isn't any result for my published product. Is it possible that Facebook Graph API Explorer is not showing the live result, or my in development mode app is not allowed to get any result or there is any other hidden restriction?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

After a bunch of trial and error, I am able to get the data with catalog_management permission, which is not stated in Facebook doc.

Comment: Hi, can you please share the solution? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: If you've setup others correctly and have products in your FB shop, you should be able to get the result by requesting `catalog_management` permission from FB prior that.

Comment: I observed in my case it was working with some IP, example: when I request from my local system it was working well,but in our AWS instance when I run same query with same auth key it was giving empty array, 
I know looks weird! pleaseHelp